# why this javascript code snippet, outerString output ”undefined“？

Tags: javascript

```
var outer = 'outer';

function fn1() {
  var outerString = outer;
  var outer = 'inner';

  console.log( outerString );
  console.log( outer );
}

fn1();
```

why outerString; // undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things are going on here:

1. The `var outer` *inside* the function is shadowing (hiding) the `outer` variable that you've declared outside the function.
2. This happens even before the `var outer` in the function, because `var` is *hoisted* to the top of the scope where it's written (so are function declarations).
3. When a variable is created, it starts out with the value `undefined`. What looks like variable initialization (`var x = 42`) is actually just an assignment that happens later when step-by-step code runs.

Your code really looks like this to the JavaScript engine:

```
var outer;                     // Global declaration for `outer`

function fn1() {               // Function declaration for `fn1`
  var outerString;             // Local decl for `outerString`
  var outer;                   // Local decl for `outer`, shadows (hides) the global one
                               // Here, both outerString and outer = `undefined`
  outerString = outer;         // No-op, they're both already `undefined`
  outer = 'inner';             // Give the inner `outer` the value `'inner'`

  console.log( outerString );  // "undefined"
  console.log( outer );        // "inner"
}

outer = 'outer';               // Note this happens after the declarations
fn1();                         // Then you call the function
```

More *(on my blog)*: [*Poor, misunderstood `var`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)

Comment: Thanks~~and nice explanation.
 var outer = 'outer';

    function fn1() {
      var inner = name;
      var another;
      console.log( name );
      console.log( inner );   // ''
      console.log( name );  // ''
      console.log( another );
    }

    fn1();
why inner and name output empty string?

Comment: @ByerGallagher: That code will result in a `ReferenceError`, as you try to read the value of `name`, which you've never declared.

Comment: yes! i think it would be an referenceError, but is out empty, and i console.log( typeof( name) ) // string, and console.log( name === '' ) // true why?

Comment: @ByerGallagher: Ah! You're doing this on a browser. On browsers, `name` is a predefined global: It's the name of the window (usually `""`).

Answer (score 2):

It is because of [variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) [hosting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting), since you have declared the variable inside, the outer scope variable will not be referenced.

Your code will look something like

```
var outer = 'outer';

function fn1() {
  var outer, outerString; //these are declared in the local scope but not yet initialized
  outerString = outer;//now outer has undefined as its value
  outer = 'inner';

  console.log( outerString );
  console.log( outer );
}

fn1();
```

- [JavaScript Scoping and Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)

Answer (score 0):

Variable declarations (and declarations in general) are processed before any code is executed, declaring a variable anywhere in the code is equivalent to declaring it at the top. [read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

form above you can conclude that `outer` is `undefined` while defining `outerString`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the variable outer is being called when outerString is called; meaning outerString is looking for a variable that does not yet exist.

Change it to

var outer = 'inner';

var outerString = outer;

Answer (score 0):

See the comments below:
This is how your code is executed by javascript.

```
var outer;
    outer = 'outer';

function fn1() {
  var outerString;
  var outer;

  /**** Here outer is declared locally but not defined ****/
  /**** Because you defined var outer inside the function so it takes the local value which is declared but not defined. ****/

  /**** Locally outer variable is defined but your are trying to assign it to outerString before defining it ****/      

  outerString = outer;         // Local variable outer
  outer = 'inner';             // This is the point where you are defining the outer in local scope.


  console.log( outerString );  // Undefined as outerString was assigned a variable which was declared but not defined.
  console.log( outer );        // This was defined locally also hence gives out value.
}

fn1();
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, remove the var outer inside your function, you already declare var outside so no need to do it again. Just write outer = "inner"; and that'll be enough.